# WP Media Gallery custom filter for media translation PHP snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I'm trying to add a filter to the WordPress media library to differentiate between original media items and their duplicates. For some reason, the filter isn't working as expected. Specifically, when I try to filter by duplicates, it shows an empty set. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Background:
I'm working on a WordPress site that uses WPML for multilingual content. Due to the nature of WPML, media items can have duplicates in different languages. I wanted to add a filter to the WordPress media library to easily differentiate between original media items and their duplicates. This would help in managing the media library more efficiently.

Problem:
I added a dropdown filter to the media library with three options: "All", "Originals", and "Duplicates". The idea is to filter media items based on whether they are originals (i.e., source language is NULL) or duplicates (i.e., source language is not NULL). However, when I try to filter by duplicates, it shows an empty set, even though there are duplicate media items in the library. The "Originals" filter seems to work, but the "Duplicates" filter does not.

Attempted Solution:
I used the restrict_manage_posts action to add the dropdown filter and the parse_query filter to modify the query based on the selected option. I joined the icl_translations table to check the source_language_code for each media item. The code seems straightforward, but for some reason, it's not working as expected.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Add filter to media library
function custom_add_media_type_filter() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ('upload.php' == $pagenow) {
        $selected = isset($_GET['media_type_filter']) ? $_GET['media_type_filter'] : 'all';
        echo '<select name="media_type_filter">';
        echo '<option value="all" ' . selected($selected, 'all', false) . '>' . __('All', 'text-domain') . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="originals" ' . selected($selected, 'originals', false) . '>' . __('Originals', 'text-domain') . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="duplicates" ' . selected($selected, 'duplicates', false) . '>' . __('Duplicates', 'text-domain') . '</option>';
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'custom_add_media_type_filter');

// Process the filter
function custom_filter_media_by_type($query) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;
    if ('upload.php' == $pagenow && isset($_GET['media_type_filter']) && $_GET['media_type_filter'] != '') {
        $join = "
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}icl_translations AS translations
            ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = translations.element_id
            AND translations.element_type = 'post_attachment'
        ";
        $query->join .= $join;
        if ($_GET['media_type_filter'] == 'originals') {
            $query->set('where', $query->get('where') . " AND translations.source_language_code IS NULL");
        } elseif ($_GET['media_type_filter'] == 'duplicates') {
            $query->set('where', $query->get('where') . " AND translations.source_language_code IS NOT NULL");
        }
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'custom_filter_media_by_type');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!